# Out of Range error in Excel VBA when trying to access array element that doesn't exist

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a very basic problem.

Context:
1) I have a column where each cell may or may not contain a list of comma separated entries.
2) I loop through each row and split each cell by a comma and feed this into an array. 
3) I then write the value for each element into the array into a new cell in a different spreadsheet.

When I add array(0), my formula works because there is always one entry (although it's not always comma separated with additional entries).

When I add array(1), my formula conditionally works because there are some instances where it would have a value from splitting the cell by a comma and accessing the second entry.

However, many times array(1) doesn't have a value and I get an subscript out of range error.

How can I conditionally check when the array element I'm accessing doesn't have a value to avoid this?

I currently have something like:

```
Workbook.Worksheets("name").Cells(x,y).Value = array(1)
```

I want to do something like:

```
If (IsEmpty(array(1))) Then
    Workbook.Worksheets("name").Cells(x,y).Value = ""
Else 
    Workbook.Worksheets("name").Cells(x,y).Value = array(1)
```

But this also threw a subscript error. Any advice?

Comment: Check the [`UBound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function) of the array.

Comment: If the array is empty, then `array(1)` will (expectedly) throw this error. You need to check whether the array has elements and/or has been initialized. In most cases, `Ubound(array)` will give you give you the maximum index. There are some edge cases IIRC that require some extraordinary workaround functions to handle.

Comment: Looking at the Ubound worked!! Thank you!! :)

Unrelated question: Can I promote a note to an answer...?

Comment: No, but you can self-answer if you prefer or prompt someone to write an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the number of elements in an array, use [`UBound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function), e.g.

```
If UBound(array) > 0 Then
    ... access array(1)
Else
    ... write a blank string.
End If
```